# Getting the text element from parent tag for each child tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a function that scrapes item and price data from [this](https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/) site

I also require a category value for each item scraped, the parent value is within the text element of `<div class="section-title">` and the child item values are within the text element's of `<div class="product-name">`

The expected output would be:

```
[{"item": "Deal 1", "price": "7.00", "category": "SPECIAL OFFERS"}
{"item": "Deal 2", "price": "6.00", "category": "SPECIAL OFFERS"}]
```

HTML sample:

```
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section-title">SPECIAL OFFERS</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="ac-product-list">
      <div class="page-title category-title" id="cat_991">
        SPECIAL OFFERS</div>
      <ol class="category-products products-list SPECIAL OFFERS">
        <li class="item">
          <div class="product-name">Deal 1</div>
          <p class="description">Chicken Fillet Sandwich, Chips<br/> & A Can Of Soft Drink</p>
          <div class="menu-right">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-52948_1646624279">
£7.00                                    </span><button style="display:none" type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGFyY29hbGdyaWxsdG90dG9uLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/52948/form_key/nWC3b6ZYcwGKrFdy/?options=cart')">
+                   </button></div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <div class="product-name">Deal 2</div>
          <p class="description">1/4lb Cheeseburger, Chips<br/> & A Can Of Soft Drink</p>
          <div class="menu-right">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-52949_791176089">
£6.00                                    </span><button style="display:none" type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGFyY29hbGdyaWxsdG90dG9uLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/52949/form_key/nWC3b6ZYcwGKrFdy/?options=cart')">
+                   </button></div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <div class="product-name">Deal 3</div>
          <p class="description">5 Breaded Chicken Strips, Chips<br/> & A Can Of Soft Drink</p>
          <div class="menu-right">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-52950_1618366957">
£6.50                                    </span><button style="display:none" type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGFyY29hbGdyaWxsdG90dG9uLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/52950/form_key/nWC3b6ZYcwGKrFdy/?options=cart')">
+                   </button></div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <div class="product-name">Deal 4</div>
          <p class="description">Chicken Burger, Chips<br/> & A Can Of Soft Drink</p>
          <div class="menu-right">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-53124_1465833177">
£6.00                                    </span><button style="display:none" type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGFyY29hbGdyaWxsdG90dG9uLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/53124/form_key/nWC3b6ZYcwGKrFdy/?options=cart')">
+                   </button></div>
        </li>
        <li class="item last">
          <div class="product-name">Combi Box</div>
          <p class="description">4 Nuggets<br/> 4 Onion Rings<br/> Chips
          </p>
          <div class="menu-right">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-53076_1586614135">
£4.50                                    </span><button style="display:none" type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('https://charcoalgrilltotton.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGFyY29hbGdyaWxsdG90dG9uLmNvLnVrLw,,/product/53076/form_key/nWC3b6ZYcwGKrFdy/')">
+                   </button></div>
        </li>
```

My code:

```
def totton_parse(soup: BeautifulSoup, vendor: str) -> list:
    """Returns list of dict: items, prices, category, vendor"""

    items = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("div", class_="product-name")]
    prices = [i.text.strip().lstrip("£") for i in soup.find_all("span", class_="regular-price")]
    category = "value"  # todo get category for each item

    item_stack = []

    for it, pr in zip(items, prices):
        item_dict = {"vendor": vendor, "items": it, "price": float(pr), "category": category}
        item_stack.append(item_dict)

    return item_stack
```

I have tried using `find_parent` and `find_previous` with no desired result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_previous` with `attrs=` parameter to find previous tag with specified class.

If `html_doc` contains the HTML snippet from the question, then:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for item in soup.select(".item"):
    name = item.select_one(".product-name").get_text(strip=True)
    price = item.select_one(".regular-price").get_text(strip=True).strip("£")
    category = item.find_previous(attrs={"class": "category-title"}).get_text(
        strip=True
    )
    print(name)
    print(price)
    print(category)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Deal 1
7.00
SPECIAL OFFERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deal 2
6.00
SPECIAL OFFERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deal 3
6.50
SPECIAL OFFERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deal 4
6.00
SPECIAL OFFERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Combi Box
4.50
SPECIAL OFFERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej really appreciate it! Had to make a slight change to catch the None values but worked as expected :)